# topology about isolated and limit point

Tags: general-topology

As a first class in topology, it is hard to prove. Can you help me?

$S\subset X^{metric}$. Let $S_1$ be the set of limit points of S. Let $S_2$ be the set of isolated points of S. Show that $\bar S = S_1\cup S_2$ and $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$.

Comment: what is the exact definition of $S_1$?

Comment: Is it not enough?

Comment: well, if $x\in S$, it is the limit of the sequence $x_n=x$....

Comment: Doesn't this apply to general topological spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only fact we need for metric spaces is that finite sets are closed (i.e. the space is $T_1$). This follows if we prove that singletons $\{p\}$ are closed (as closed sets are preserved by finite unions). And if $x \neq p$, the open ball $B(x,d(x,p))$ misses $\{p\}$ so every point of $X\setminus\{p\}$ is an interior point of it, so $X\setminus\{p\}$ is open and thus $\{p\}$ is closed.

Now consider a point $x \in \overline{S}$. This means that every open ball around $x$ intersects $S$, by definition. There are two mutually exclusive types: every ball intersects $S$ in infinitely many points, *or* there exists an open ball $B(x,r)$ that intersects $S$ in a finite set $F \subset S$. It's clear that exactly one of these must be the case.

If the former, then clearly $x$ is a limit point of $S$, so $x \in S_1$. If the latter is the case, then $B(x,r) \cap (X\setminus(F\setminus\{x\}))$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ (intersection of two open sets, as finite sets are closed!) and can only intersect $S$ in $\{x\}$ and it *must* intersect $S$, so this open set shows that $\{x\}$ is an isolated point of $S$, so $x \in S_2$.

The reverse is clear: all limit points of $S$ are in the closure $\overline{S}$, and all points of $S$ (all isolated points in particular) are also in $\overline{S}$.

Comment: Dividing two cases helps me. I have read carefully. Then I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @topy You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In order to definition isolated points are those which are not limit points ($S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$). So every point in $S$ is isolated or not. This conclude that $S=S_1\cup S_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \bar S$, then there are sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in S$ and $x_n \to x$. There are two cases.

1. For some particular sequence, there are arbitrarily large $n$ for which $x_n \neq x$
2. For all such sequences there is an $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $x_n = x$.

For (1), find a sequence in $S \setminus \{x\}$ which converges to  $x$. What does that tell you about $x$?

For (2), what does that tell you about $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting $S_{1}$ to be the set of points $v$ such that for every neighborhood of $v$, $U_{v}$ we have that $U_{v}\cap S\setminus\{v\}\neq\emptyset$. Interpreting $S_{2}$ to be the set of points $v\in S$ such that there is a neighborhood of $v$, $U_{v}$ that contains finitely many points of $S$.

Let $v\in\bar{S}$. Then $v$ is either an element of $S$ or else it is a boundary point of $S$. In the former case, if $v$ is an interior point then $v\in S_{1}$, else it is an isolated point in which case it is in $S_{2}$. If $v$ is a boundary point then it is a limit point of $S$ implying that it is in $S_{1}$.

If $v\in S_{2}$ then it is an element of $\bar{S}$ because $S\subseteq\bar{S}$. If $v\in S_{1}$ it is either interior to $S$ or is a boundary point of $S$, in either case $v\in\bar{S}$.

$S_{1}\cap S_{2}=\emptyset$. If not then there is a point $v\in S$ such that there is a neighborhood of $v$, $U_{v}$ that contains only finitely many points of $S$. We can then find a another neighborhood of $v$ that contains only $v$ by taking the open ball around $v$ with $\epsilon$ equal to less than the distance between $v$ and it's closest neighbor, but note that this would give us a neighborhood of $v$ that does not contain a point of $S$ other than $v$ which means $v$ can't be a limit point. It must then be that $S_{1}\cap S_{2}=\emptyset$.